# How to show page title in blog post of wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I want to show the page title in single post page of wordpress theme. I tried to use `<?php echo get_the_title() ?>` but it return the post title, not the page title.

basically I want to show MY page title, in this case "Blog" below my header area in single.php file. how do I make it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get page title you need to use WordPress API function use the code below

```
    <?php
    $post_7 = get_post($id); 
    $title = $post_7->post_title;
    ?>
```

In wordpress both posts and pages have ids. So same function will work to get title of either post or page.

You have to pass this parameter to get the title of the page.

For reference see this link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Comment: didn't understand it properly, where do I put that code?
sorry I'm a new learner.